# How can I merge strings in the system function?

Tags: c

I have some string, `foo` and I want to be able to run something like `as foo.s -o foo.o`. If this were `printf`, I would be able to do `printf("as %s.s -o %s.o", foo, foo);`. What I want to be able to do is something like that, except with the `system` function. How can I do this? Using the same approach as `printf` gives me an error saying I've passed too many arguments.

In my code, I have:

```
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
     system("as %s.s -o %s.o", *(argv + i), *(argv + i));
   }
```

But this gives me an error saying I have too many arguments. I suppose I could go through the painful process of looping through character arrays, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: please add some code snipped on what have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't forget the [`exec` family of functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) which take discrete arguments. This largely avoids the need to "shell escape" things. If `foo` contains a space this method of smashing things together produces invalid results.

Comment: @tadman Perfect, execv works for me

Comment: the `as` is the 'portable GNU assembler`  So your call to `system()` seems to be trying to take an assembly source file, and run that through the assembler to produce an object file of the same name.  Do I understand your objective correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html):

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "as %s.s -o %s.o", argv[i], argv[i]);
if (size < 0) {
  return ERROR; // handle error as you like
}
char *p = malloc(++size); // we add the +1 for the nul terminate byte
if (p == NULL) {
  return ERROR;
}
int ret = snprintf(p, size, "as %s.s -o %s.o", argv[i], argv[i]);
if (ret < 0) {
  free(p);
  return ERROR;
}

system(p);

free(p); // if you don't need it anymore
```

Note: The only problem is that for obscure reason, `snprintf()` don't return `size_t`. But it's the only fonction we can use in std to do what you want.

Comment: This answers the question of formatting strings, thank you for that. I'll mark this as the answer since it technically does what I want it to. But I think for this particular program I'll use execv :)

Comment: @AlSmith that definitively a better choice ;)

Comment: Don't forget to `free` the result if it succeeds.

Comment: If `malloc()` is used, it is necessary to `free(p)` AFTER the `system()` call, to avoid a leak.       It is also possible to use basic string functions (`strlen()`, `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, etc) to work out required length and copy the strings as needed - arguably preferable if you need to add multiple command line arguments to a single string.